# Populating multi column combobox in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm newbie in vba excel, but i didn't find yet what i'm looking for in google.

I want a list like this in my combo box

```
BUS     B
APPLE   A
SUGAR   S
JELLY   J
```

I do like this in the past

```
Dim listEntries(3, 2) As Variant

listEntries(0, 0) = "A"
listEntries(0, 1) = "Apple"
listEntries(1, 0) = "S"
listEntries(1, 1) = "Sugar"
listEntries(2, 0) = "J"
listEntries(2, 1) = "Jelly"

Me.ComboBox1.List = listEntries
```

but now days the data become so many. I want the list is coming from another sheet list. I found this in Google. but it is still not works

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cItem As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")

For Each cItem In ws.Range("ItemList")
  With Me.cboItem
    .AddItem cItem.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cItem.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next cItem
End Sub
```

Is there any missed in my code or is there another way to get the multiple value from another sheet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop if you just want to put a range in the list:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.cboItem.List = Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("ItemList").Resize(, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Please be specific - what happens exactly? (I use this sort of code all the time)

Comment: Thank you very much... yes it is work. I was typo when type UserForm_Initialize() i typed UserForms_Initialize()...

Comment: Thank you very much... yes it is work. I was typo when type UserForm_Initialize() i typed UserForms_Initialize()...